# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=login_filter (has extras) }

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=login_filter (has extras) } 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1798)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:843)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
    at com.example.carlos.assigmentcarlos.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

Well, I am trying to run this project, but this error is appearing. I am not sure why Intent is not working.

This is my Main:

```
package com.example.carlos.assigmentcarlos;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button Login, Register, Delete, Update;
    int status = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);
        Register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Reg);
        Delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Delete);
        Update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Update);
        Login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = 1;
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("status", status);
                Intent i  = new Intent("login_filter");
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i  = new Intent("register_filter");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        Update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = 2;
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("status", status);
                Intent i  = new Intent("login_filter");
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        Delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = 3;
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("status", status);
                Intent i  = new Intent("login_filter");
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my register:

```
package com.example.carlos.assigmentcarlos;

/**
 * Created by Carlos on 22/04/2016.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Register extends Activity {
    Button Login;
    EditText USERNAME,USERPASS;
    String username,userpass;
    Context CTX = this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
        Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_login);
        USERNAME = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        USERPASS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_pass);
        Login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
                int status = b.getInt("status");
                if(status == 1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    username = USERNAME.getText().toString();
                    userpass = USERPASS.getText().toString();
                    DatabaseOperations DOP = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
                    Cursor CR = DOP.getInformation(DOP);
                    CR.moveToFirst();
                    boolean loginstatus = false;
                    String NAME = "";
                    do
                    {
                        if(username.equals(CR.getString(0))&& (userpass.equals(CR.getString(1))))
                        {
                            loginstatus = true;
                            NAME = CR.getString(0);
                        }
                    } while(CR.moveToNext());

                    if(loginstatus)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Success----\n Welcome "+NAME, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Failed---- ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }
                else if(status == 2)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    username = USERNAME.getText().toString();
                    userpass = USERPASS.getText().toString();
                    DatabaseOperations DOP = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
                    Cursor CR = DOP.getInformation(DOP);
                    CR.moveToFirst();
                    boolean loginstatus = false;
                    String NAME = "";
                    do
                    {
                        if(username.equals(CR.getString(0))&& (userpass.equals(CR.getString(1))))
                        {
                            loginstatus = true;
                            NAME = CR.getString(0);
                        }
                    } while(CR.moveToNext());

                    if(loginstatus)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Success----\n Welcome "+NAME, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Intent i = new Intent("update_filter");
                        Bundle BN = new Bundle();
                        BN.putString("user_name",NAME );
                        BN.putString("user_pass",userpass );
                        i.putExtras(BN);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Failed---- ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }
                else if(status == 3)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    username = USERNAME.getText().toString();
                    userpass = USERPASS.getText().toString();
                    DatabaseOperations DOP = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
                    Cursor CR = DOP.getInformation(DOP);
                    CR.moveToFirst();
                    boolean loginstatus = false;
                    String NAME = "";
                    do
                    {
                        if(username.equals(CR.getString(0))&& (userpass.equals(CR.getString(1))))
                        {
                            loginstatus = true;
                            NAME = CR.getString(0);
                        }
                    } while(CR.moveToNext());

                    if(loginstatus)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Success----\n Welcome "+NAME, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent("delete_filter");
                        Bundle B = new Bundle();
                        B.putString("user_name",NAME );
                        i.putExtras(B);
                        startActivity(i);

                        finish();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Failed---- ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }

                    Intent i = new Intent("delete_filter");
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentCenter="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I noticed that the code-parts from `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` towards `} while(CR.moveToNext());` is the exact same for all three if's. Why not put that part of the code in a separate method?

Answer (score 1):

Replace all occurrences of:

```
Intent i  = new Intent("...");
```

(where `...` is `login_filter`, etc.)

with `Intent` constructors that take the Java class as the second parameter, such as:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
```

This will be somewhat difficult for you, since you decided to have more than one thing named `Register` (an `Activity` class and a widget).

You want an `Intent` that identifies what it is that you are trying to start. The simplest and most secure way to do that, for starting your own private activities, is to use the `Intent(Context, Class)` constructor.

For example, in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Activities/Explicit), I use such an "explicit `Intent`" to start an activity:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.exint;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class ExplicitIntentsDemoActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  public void showOther(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class));
  }
}
```

Comment: Already tried that and throw me an error message "Cannot resolve Contructor"

Comment: @Calitoz: For those cases, see if you are inside of some anonymous inner class (e.g., `new OnClickListener()...`). If so, prefix `this` with the activity class (e.g., `MainActivity.this`).